# How do I call a person working in a higher position than me in company?

Tags: word-request

In a company, there are various ranks of positions. And some people are working in a higher position than me.

Is there any word indicating anyone working in a higher position than me?

He/she can work inside in the same team or he/she might not, just only in the same company. He can be just above you or he can work at a much higher position.

He is my ______.

What is a suitable word for the blank?

---

I've been doing googling and I come across the word 'superior'. Is this a suitable word? Or, is it unsuitable to indicate someone by rank? Is it ok to address him 'my colleague'?

Comment: He is my senior.

Comment: @Umesh I tend to think an old person with 'senior'. Is it still used if the person is younger than me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you use the word *address*, I think you are asking about what to call such a person when you are speaking to someone else.

If the person is only a little above you in rank, you might call them your *line manager* or *supervisor*. In a social setting, it would probably be OK to refer to them as your colleague. However, if they are much senior to you it would probably be more polite to say "Mr X is a head of department at the firm where I work," or whatever is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Superior. Anyone who is higher up than you in an organisation can be referred to as your superior.